# Interpreting a low phi-coefficient, but a high regression correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I'm conducting statistical analysis on two categorical binary variables. My phi-coefficient yields only 0.09 at a 0.01 significance level. However, when I conduct multiple logistic regression on the variables (with other variables included), the coefficient I get for this particular variable is 0.54,  with Exp(B) of 1.7294. The p-value for the coefficient is very low, 0.002.

To me this seems counter-intuitive - the variables have a low association on account of the phi-coefficient, but regression shows that the presence of one makes the other 1.7294 times more likely, and the result is statistically significant too.

Could someone please explain what is wrong with my interpretation, and guide me as to how I should correctly interpret these results? Many thanks.

Comment: The critical phrase in your question is "with other variables included".

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: You are not comparing like with like so there is no particular reason to expect the same thing to happen.